# Quotation marks around first definition of a term and its parenthesized abbreviation

Tags: abbreviations, quotations

Suppose a document is using the term "Internet Protocol" for the first time, along with its abbreviation, "IP".  For example:

> Rar rar rar... "Internet Protocol (IP)".

Are there any guidelines as to whether the quotation marks should go around both the full term and its abbreviation, or just the term itself?

i.e. rather than what is shown above, is it preferable to use:

> Rar rar rar... "Internet Protocol" (IP).

As a follow on question, does the advice change when terms are italicized instead of quoted?  For example:

> Rar rar rar...*Internet Protocol (IP)*.

versus:

> Rar rar rar...*Internet Protocol* (IP).

Comment: I think it's Primarily Opinion-based which style guide you endorse (or which style guide endorses *you/your style*, depending how you see it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot depends on what the "rar rar rar" part of the sentence is saying. If the relevant sentence says something like this (adapted from the [Wikipedia article on Internet Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol)):

> The primary protocol in the Internet layer of the Internet protocol suite is termed the Internet Protocol (IP).

then a number of style guides (including *Words Into Type*, third edition, at page 137, and *Chicago Manual of Style*, fifteenth edition, at 7.62, under "Words and Letters Used as Words") would treat both *Internet Protocol* and *IP* as "words [or] phrases used as words." According to Chicago,

> **7.62** *Words and phrases used as words.* When a word or term is not used functionally but is referred to as the word or term itself, it is either italicized or enclosed in quotation marks.

If you followed this form, you would say either

> is termed the *Internet Protocol* (*IP*).

or

> is termed the "Internet Protocol" ("IP").

Logically it doesn't make sense to put quotation marks around the entire expression because doing so would imply that the term is normally stated as "Internet Protocol (IP)"—with the trailing abbreviation in parentheses—every time it is mentioned.

On the other hand, if your "rar rar rar" sentence says something like this (again adapted from the Wikipedia article):

> Within the Internet protocol suite, the principal communications protocol for relaying datagrams across network boundaries is the Internet Protocol (IP).

you'll find Chicago's relevant recommendations in section 7.57 under "Highlighting Terms in Specific Contexts":

> **7.57** *Italics.* Key terms in a particular context are often italicized on their first occurrence. Thereafter they are best set in roman.

The crucial phrase here is "are often italicized." Unlike in the instance of words used as words—where Chicago comes out four-square for italics or quotation marks—in the case of key terms, Chicago declines to endorse any particular treatment. The likeliest approaches are:

> ... across network boundaries is the Internet Protocol (IP).

or:

> ... across network boundaries is the *Internet Protocol* (*IP*).

or

> ... across network boundaries is the "Internet Protocol" ("IP").

Punctuation (such as quotation marks) and special typographical treatments (such as italics) are not fundamentally elements of grammar; they are elements of style. And style choices and guidelines are as varied and various as grains of sand on a small beach. Readers do appreciate stylistic consistency within a document—but that is mainly because once they've adjusted to the author's style preferences, those preferences recede into the background, where they belong. All you have to do (assuming that you are free to make your own style decisions) is choose a key-terms style that you find easy to work with and then enforce it consistently.

Comment: Excellent answer. The key thing, I think, is what you say at the bottom. Pick a format and then stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason to put quotes at all. Simply say Internet Protocol (IP). It's a straightforward term used in a straightforward way. No opportunity for confusion or anything by the reader.